# create row with dynamic drop down and input boxes with jquery

Tags: jquery

[image: Image enclosed for your reference.]. 
Please find attached image for your reference. 
Please refer to the "Scope Cat" Dropdownlist. I have added 2 rows by click even using jquery and both rows contain same drop down list. However they should display Scope Item and Billing Hours basis on the selection from the dropdown from each row. But my issue is, first row is working fine and displaying correct data whereas if i select any option from the second row, it is displaying the same data as first row instead of the data for selected option in second row.I know issue pertains to unique id for each select option but i am unable to create unique id for each select option through jquery.

**Requirement**: I am trying to build a table where the rows would be added on click event with one drop down in each row (Options would be dynamically displayed from database) and 3 input text boxes. After adding the row, I need to display data on input text boxes basis the selection of the drop down in the row.

**What achieved so far**: I am able to create a row based on click event through jquery and also able to display relevant data in the input boxes bases the selection of the drop down using .change(function(){...}) in jquery, but limited to only first row data.

**Issue required your support**: I am able to add as many rows as required, Able to display drop down list dynamically on all added rows. But Issue is, after adding more than 1 rows, all input fields are displaying the same data as of first row. I am not able to display row specific data basis drop down selection of that row. For example, If i select Option1 from drop down in first row, it displays correct data in the input fields for first row as per the drop down selection. But when i select different option in second row for example: Option2, Even then it displays first row data basis the first row selection Option1. It seems the issue with Select option class or Id which should be made unique i believe which i am unable to do so. Your expert advice is required to understand where i am going wrong. Provided below is the code which i had done so far as mentioned above.

```
<div class="item form-group">
     <table class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
       <thead>
         <tr class="headings">
            <th class="column-title">Scope Cat </th>
            <th class="column-title">Scope Item </th>
            <th class="column-title">Billing Hours</th>
            <th class="column-title">Costing per Scope</th>
         </tr>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" name="addnewscope" type="button" value="add Scope" onClick ="addRow(this)">
     </thead>
     <tbody id="addnewscopesfromid">

     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
  function addRow(btn) {  
        $('.scopecategory23221').html('');
        $('#addnewscopesfromid').append('<tr><td class="column-title"><select class="form-control scopecategory23221" name="scopecategory23221"><option value="">Scope Category</option></select></td><td class="column-title"><input name="scopeitem22313324"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 scopeitem22313324"  type="text" value=""></td><td class="column-title"><input name="scopebillinghours22313324"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 scopebillinghours22313324"  type="text" value=""></td>  <td class="column-title"><input name="scopebillinghourlyrate11213423"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 scopebillingcost11213423"  type="text" value=""></td></tr>');
        var scopelist='Scopelist';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "includes/getcontactnames.php",
            data: scopelist,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, field) {
                    var scopeitemId=field.scopeitemId;
                    var scopeitemsname=field.scopeitemName;
                    $('.scopecategory23221').append('<option value="'+scopeitemId+'">'+scopeitemsname+'</option>');

                });
            }
        });
        $('.scopecategory23221').change(function(){
        var scopeCat =document.getElementsByClassName('scopecategory23221');
        var scopeCat1 = scopeCat[0].options[scopeCat[0].selectedIndex].value;
        alert(scopeCat1);
        var scopedataString= 'scopecategory='+scopeCat1;
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "includes/getcontactnames.php",
                data: scopedataString,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, field) {
                        var scopeitemname=field.scopeitemName;
                        var scopebillinghours=field.billingHours;
                        $('.scopeitem22313324').val(scopeitemname);
                        $('.scopebillinghours22313324').val(scopebillinghours);
                    });
                }
            });
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try something like this.

```
<div id="box">
   <table class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
        <thead>
             <tr class="headings">
                <th class="column-title">Scope Cat </th>
                <th class="column-title">Scope Item </th>
                <th class="column-title">Billing Hours</th>
                <th class="column-title">Costing per Scope</th>
             </tr>
             <input class="btn btn-primary" name="addnewscope" type="button" 
               value="add Scope" id ="add">
        </thead>
 <tbody id="addnewscopesfromid">

 </tbody></table></div>
```

Then in your script file

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    $('#add').on('click', function () {

        var inp = $('#box');
        var i = $('input').length + 1;
        $('<div id="box' + i + '" class="col-lg-12"><table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-responsive">\n\
                <tbody>\n\
                        <td>Your Table Values</td>\n\
                    </tr>\n\
                </tbody>\n\
            </table></div>').appendTo(inp);

        i++;
    });
}
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#add').click(function () {

            var dataId = '';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'includes/getcontactnames.php',
                async: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: scopedataString,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var $select = $('#select-box Id');
                    $select.find('option').remove();
                    for (var i in data.data) {
                        $select.append('<option value=' + data.data[i].id + '>' + data.data[i].item_name + '</option>');
                    }
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps you.